# Cannot Import NPM Workspace Scoped Module Subfolder

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, turborepo

I currently working on this repository which uses NPM Workspace, and Turborepo. The repository consisted of many modules, just how a monorepo is. The general layout of the repository are as follows,

```
+-- src
    +-- package.json (workspace definition to all module under folder common and modules)
    +-- common
        +-- commonModule (@example/common-module)
            +-- package.json
            +-- tsconfig.json
            +-- src
                +-- index.ts (exports liba)
                +-- liba
                    +-- a.ts (exports code)
                    +-- index.ts (exports a.ts)
    +-- modules
        +-- mainModules (@example/main-module)
            +-- package.json
            +-- tsconfig.json
            +-- src
                +-- index.ts
```

The case is that in the `src/modules/mainModules/src/index.ts` I try to import the a.ts from `@example/common-module`. The first thing I tried are something like this,

```js
import { a } from "@example/common-module/src/liba";
```

But the result after building it using `tsc` and running it using node 16 as usual. It gives out error that the module are not found, the error code are like this,

```
...
Error: Cannot find module '@example/common-module/src/liba'
...
```

While when I tried to import it from the root like,

```js
import { lib } from "@example/common-module";

lib.a
```

It works just fine, node is able to find the modules corresponding to the import statement. Is node are not able to import through subfolder of a scoped modules? Or there are ways to get around this? All the modules do show up when I do `npm list` as well.

For reference all of the modules are using this exact `tsconfig.json`,

```json
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/node16-strictest/tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["ESNext"],
    "outDir": "dist"
  }
}
```

The extended file are just tsconfig base strictest version for node 16 that can be [seen in their repository](https://github.com/tsconfig/bases/blob/96274973952a623d9f2e310987ceb4a19dcc362c/bases/node16-strictest.combined.json).

Comment: Did you get any fix for this?

Comment: @Priya I think I've fixed it by changing the import to "@example/common-module/ **dist** /src/liba". As I was compiling the typescript code to /dist